# Searching for a javascript library to validate JSON against OpenAPI schema

Tags: openapi

I am searching for a JS library (ideally usable in the browser) to:

1. check a particular JSON payload (typically a response from an API) against an OpenAPI 3.0 schema (YAML or JSON)
2. ideally decorate that JSON payload with information extracted from the OpenAPI 3.0 schema (eg. documentation information)

   - alternatively allow callbacks to external handling functions for each error / match in the validation step

Answer (score 0):

As for...

1. You could try one of the following:

   - https://jsonschemalint.com/#/version/draft-07/markup/json
   - https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/#
2. I would look into and try to build your requirements on top of ajv

   - https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv